# Testing a silverlight application with statlight on Windows Server 2008 r2

Tags: silverlight, integration-testing

I followed the instructions on [pyxis-tech.com](http://pyxis-tech.com/blog/2011/01/24/how-to-run-silverlight-automated-tests-on-tfs-build-server/) to test our Silverlight application on TFS2010 on a Windows 2008 r2 Server. If I run the test as part of a build they all fail. Running them on the server as the same user reveals the following:

```
------------------ Test Failed ------------------
Test Namespace:  [StatLight]
Test Class:  [CannotFigureItOut]
Test Method: [NotEnoughContext]
Other Info: A Silverlight MessageBox dialog was automatically closed.
Caption: One or more ActiveX controls could not be displayed because either:

1) Your current security settings prohibit running ActiveX controls on this page
, or
2) You have blocked a publisher of one of the controls.

As a result, the page might not display correctly.
Dialog Message:
Web Browser
-------------------------------------------------
```

Statlight opens it's browser which displays a dialog with the same error message before closing it after a minute or so. The the browser displays the silverlight installation ad even though the silverlight runtime is already installed on the computer.
I've granted the executing user a ridiculous amount of privileges but still had no success. If anyone has had this problem before, I'd appreciate a little help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure the service executing StatLight has desktop interactivity enabled.

On the services Log On tab you have to check the "Allow service to interact with desktop"

Comment: I tried your solution. Unfortunately it didn't change anything. I still get the same error message.

Comment: What version of silverlight is installed?